# How can I retrieve the string passed after ? in a URL in a JSP

Tags: java, jsp, url, servlets

I have a servlet that communicates with MySQL database and displays the information receive using a JSP (using offset and limit in MySQL). I want to implement pagination and buttons to sort the data. All of the required info for the SQL query is sent through the URL so it looks something like

> http://localhost:8080/proj2/SearchMovieListServlet?txt_movie_genre=Biography&txt_order_by=title&txt_sql_order=ASC&txt_sql_limit=5&txt_pg=1

and what I want to accomplish is href a "next" and "previous" button and link it to the URL above, but with the txt_pg incremented/decremented by 1. How can I do this easily without rebuilding the URL?

Comment: suppose this [post](https://ibytecode.com/blog/pagination-in-servlet-and-jsp/) has a good example of implementation of pagination with mysq & jsp.

Comment: @RajithPemabandu whenever I try accessing that page it crashes my browser (on mobile and desktop)

Comment: it may be helpful if you can share the stack trace or the exception.